# Parallel Date Sales SQL View

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2014

I have a challenge which I can't seem to resolve on my own and now need help!

I have a requirement to show parallel year date sales via SQL and by that I mean if today (20/08/2015) Customer A has purchased products worth 500, I want to know how much Customer A spent on the same day last year (so 20/08/2014).

Here's a [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/7f7b0/1) where I've built everything (I reckoned that would be easiest for you guys). I have 3 dimensions (DimProduct, DimDate and DimCustomer), a fact table (FactSales) and a view (VW_ParallelSales) which I've built on top. I have also left a query on the right hand side with what I'm trying to achieve. If you run the query you will see that for Antonio, the SaleAmount on 20140820 was 3500 and if you look at the very bottom of the table, you can see there's one more record for Antonio in the fact table on 20150820 for 6500. So esentially, what I want is to have that 3500 which was sold on 20140820 (which is the parallel year date of 20150820) under the column ParallelSales (which at the moment is showing as NULL).

It all works like a charm if I don't include the ProductKey in the view and have just the CustomerKey ([see this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/183e8/1)). However, as soon as I add the Product Key, because there is no exact match of CustomerKey-ProductKey that has happened in the past, I'm getting NULLS for ParallelSales (or at least that's what I think the reason is).

What I want to be able to do is then use the view and join on both DimCustomer and DimProduct and run queries both ways, i.e.:

Query 1: How much did Customer A spend today vs today last year?
Query 2: How much of Product A did we sell today vs today last year?

At the moment, as is, I need to have 2 views for that - one that joins the two sub-queries in the view on CustomerKey and the other one - on ProductKey (and obviously the dates).

I know it's a lot to ask but I do need to get this to work and would appreciate your help immensely! Thanks :)

Comment: I need you to explain why your second fiddle doesn't solve your query1 question. You say the problem is the null and want the previous sale. And that is exact what you got from second fiddle.

Comment: For Query2. There isn't any ProductKey with sales in one year and previous year on your data sample.

Comment: Yeah I know, I'm just testing something now. Will be back in a bit!

Comment: Hi Juan. So what we did in the end is abandoned the SQL views and instead created aliases of the fact table (one to calculate parallel quarter dates, one for parallel years and so on). We then joined those to the other dimensions. We had to change the date dimension to cater for the different number of days in each month (e.g. added duplicates for dates with incrementing datekey integers) and now the data is rolling up correctly.

Answer (score 2):

For customer sales in diferent years.

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/7f7b0/17)

```
SELECT DimCustomer.CustomerName,
       VW_Current.Saledate,
       VW_Current.ParallelDate,
       VW_Current.CurrentSales,
       VW_Previous.CurrentSales as ParallelSale

FROM   DimCustomer 
       INNER JOIN VW_ParallelSales VW_Current
           ON DimCustomer.CustomerKey = VW_Current.CustomerKey
       LEFT JOIN VW_ParallelSales VW_Previous
           ON VW_Current.ParallelDate = VW_Previous.Saledate
          AND DimCustomer.CustomerKey = VW_Previous.CustomerKey
ORDER BY 1, 2
```

For productkey

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/7f7b0/22)

```
With sales as (
    SELECT 
           DimProduct.ProductKey,
           DimProduct.ProductName,
           VW_ParallelSales.Saledate,
           VW_ParallelSales.ParallelDate,
           VW_ParallelSales.CurrentSales,
           VW_ParallelSales.ParallelSales
    FROM   DimProduct INNER JOIN VW_ParallelSales ON DimProduct.ProductKey = 
           VW_ParallelSales.ProductKey
)
SELECT 
   s_recent.ProductName,
   s_recent.Saledate ThisYear,
   s_old.Saledate PreviousYear,
   s_recent.CurrentSales CurrentSales,
   s_old.CurrentSales ParallelSales
FROM 
    SALES s_recent 
    left outer join SALES s_old 
        on s_recent.saledate = s_old.saledate + 10000
       and s_recent.ProductKey = s_old.ProductKey
```

Comment: Thanks, Juan. However, if I switch this to Products then I'm getting the same result which is wrong. No cars were purchased on 20140820, only on 20150820. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/7f7b0/18

Comment: Yes, I just realize that. Q: Why your second fiddle doesn't solve  Query1? can't  you just substract sales?

Comment: Second fiddle does solve it but I'm not after the difference. I just want current and past sales as two columns that's fine. However, I need something that works on both customers and products as well as on customers and products together (at the moment there's no possible combination of customer-product). Somehow, I need to achieve the same granularity as the fact table so I can aggregate on whatever I want afterwards.

Comment: Ohh you see my first attempt too :P. What you mean together? Because the same query **can't** solve both

Comment: BTW you did a great Job providing the fiddle. But because the text was very long to read. A picture with desire output would be great too .

Comment: Regarding your first comment your miss the productkey join. I add the fiddle. But again no sale data any item for a consecutive year.