# SQL Count between dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to do what in my head is a simple thing but failing to apply in SQL. Basically, I have two tables - one is called CarHires which consists of only three columns - CarID, StartDate (when a car is rented) and EndDate (when a car is returned). And a date dimension - DimDate.

What I'm trying to achieve is to count the number of cars that are out rented on every single day.

This is the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/40559/2) I've mocked up to make things easy.

The answer should be the following:

```
Date      : NumberOfCars
---------------------------
2015-09-07:     1
2015-09-08:     2
2015-09-09:     3
2015-09-10:     4
2015-09-11:     4
2015-09-12:     2
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You can have days without car rental? And if yes, would you like have that row with `NumeberOfCars = 0`  or just skip it from the result?

Comment: Yes, please (have it with 0's). That would make sense!

Comment: Looks like Lamak already beat me on this one. Remember accept the answer as correct if that help you. Like the one i give you [last time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32125779/parallel-date-sales-sql-view) and I never hear from you

Comment: Thanks, Juan. I will reply to your previous one now. To be honest, we were still doing this even this week and I'll let you know in the comments what we did to kind of make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
SELECT  D.Fulldate,
        ISNULL(COUNT(*),0) AS NumberofCars
FROM DimDate D
LEFT JOIN CarHires C
  ON D.Fulldate BETWEEN C.Startdate AND C.Enddate
GROUP BY D.Fulldate
ORDER BY D.Fulldate;
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

You are incorrectly joining DimDate and CarHires based on `startDate`,  `full inner join` is not needed:

```
select dimdate.Fulldate,
COUNT(CarID) AS NumberofCars   
FROM DimDate, CarHires     
WHERE dimdate.Fulldate BETWEEN CarHires.Startdate AND CarHires.Enddate    
GROUP BY dimdate.Fulldate
```